# bash - for loop in command line

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Could you please advise , I'm trying to run a "for" loop on a shell command line

```
for i in `seq 4`; do `wireshark &`; done
```

From some reason the loop isn't finish and only 1 wireshark window is open

Could you please advise?
[image]

Comment: Since you'll likely get comments or even answers on that, your loop would be prettier to the modern shell scripter if it was written as `for ((i=0; i<4; i++)); do wireshark &; done`. That most likely won't fix your problem though

Comment: Why on earth did you put `wireshark &` in backticks?

Comment: Wireshark needs a GUI and so you won't be able to run it to the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't want to put `wireshark &` in backticks.  The shell that executes your loop creates a subshell to run wireshark and is waiting for that subshell to close all of its open file descriptors that are writing to stdout so that it can collect the data written.  (That's what the bacticks do!).  If you just want to run wireshark in the background, then this should work:

```
for ...; do wireshark & done
```

Note that backticks is pretty ancient syntax, and `$()` has been preferred since the mid 90s at least.  If you're going to use `seq` you should write it as `for i in $(seq 4); do ...`.  You're using `bash`, so you could do `for((i=0; i <4; i++))`.  There are a lot of ways to do the iteration, but that's not relevant to the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `seq` external command in bash and `` `wireshark &` `` is not correct - backticks are used for command substitution but
notice that [`$()` is recommended over backticks these
days](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/sc2006). It should be:

```
for i in {1..4}; do wireshark & done
```

Answer (score -2):

You may try this

```
for VARIABLE in file1
do
    command1 on $VARIABLE
done
```